# Is it possible to convert iphone application to Windows Phone 7 application

Tags: iphone, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to convert iphone application which is build using Xcode to Windows Phone 7 application which is build using C#.?

Or is there any tool to convert.?

Can we build an application in HTML5 and deploy it on windows Phone 7.?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Best Regards,
Krishna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not Possible to Convert the iphone sdk application which is written in objective c to C#.
But using **Monotouch** http://xamarin.com/monotouch ,you can write code in C# which will be compatible for iPhone and can use it for other platForms also.

Comment: is there any platform where we can build once and deploy it in multiple devices such as windows phone 7, iphone and andriod.?

Comment: @user1220664:[Monotouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch), [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/) are the platforms which will helps to make cross platform applications.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, there are cross platform development tools available, including  tools from http://phonegap.com/, http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/ and http://www.xamarin.com. These are great solutions if you want to start on a greenfield project, or if you are embarking on a major new version across all platforms.

If you want/need to port an existing Objective-C app, however, then I don't believe there are any tools available for you. One thing that may helps is that Microsoft have produced some useful "how do I port" guides for iOS, for Android and for Qt - see:

- http://wp7mapping.interoperabilitybridges.com/Library?source=iPhone
- http://windowsphone.interoperabilitybridges.com/media/1254/wp7%20dev%20guide%20for%20iphone%20app%20developers.pdf

Answer (score 0):

use `PhoneGap` library to build your App/Product

ship it with multiple environment

it is javascript library

[PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)

Comment: Can we deploy it in windows phone 7, iphone and andriod if we use PhoneGap.??

Comment: You should check that list of supported features: [http://phonegap.com/about/features] because not all features are supported on all platforms. But in general PhoneGap app can be deployed into Android app.

Comment: Goods News.. PhoneGap supports Windows Phone now.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/architectsrule/archive/2012/01/19/phonegap-now-fully-supports-windows-phone.aspx